# Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App

Tags: android, server, google-signin

Can I integrate Google Sign-in into my android app without designing a backend server? If yes, then can I somehow get a list of all email addresses being used for the app without the server?

Comment: Right now I can think only in Firebase. Is serverless authentication made easy. Really easy. And fast. Really fast. [Check out this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/)

Comment: @joaquin Hi, I haven't implemented it yet but right now it looks like this is exactly what a freelancer like me who doesnt want to do SQL coding needs. THANKS!
Right now, I'm going to follow this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Answer (score 1):

Yes You Can Google Sign with   without designing a backend server

This Tutorial Will Help You

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/